# C Programming Using a specific Host IP to connect to server

Tags: c, networking, client-side

I am looking at a machine with multiple IP address (ex ethernet and wireless) and need my client to connect to a server using a specific Client IP address.  I can perform this easy in Java (done doing the Socket() with 4 args), but the only reference to use a specific host IP address that I can see is with using bind() but as far as I know that only is used for servers.

Synopsis:
Client has 2 IP address (ethernet and wireless) trying to connect to a server.. but using a specific IP (don't need to worry about "finding" the IP addresses as they will be in a config file or DEFINE

Not a windows only answer but a C programing that is portable (I use mac osx/linux usually but also windows)

Answer (score 1):

I've never done this before but I think you can bind a socket to an ip address and then use connect with that socket. The pertinent section from here http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/connect.html states:

> If the socket has not already been bound to a local address, connect()
>   shall bind it to an address which, unless the socket's address family
>   is AF_UNIX, is an unused local address.

Which implies that bind can be used before connect.

Answer (score 1):

Your reference is correct. If you use [bind()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/bind.html), then that address will be used to bind the client socket to the interface you want to use. bind() is not only used for server sockets.

Comment: @Sashang, Spell and Jay (will use one post vise 3) Thnx for the clarification.  I will write up the code today, experiment and post my findings.

Answer (score 0):

https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/multi/syscalls.html#bind

> By using the AI_PASSIVE flag, I'm telling the program to bind to the
>   IP of the host it's running on. If you want to bind to a specific
>   local IP address, drop the AI_PASSIVE and put an IP address in for the
>   first argument to getaddrinfo().